# HTTP Traffic Monitoring for Automated Testing

Tags: http, selenium, testing, browser, monitoring

I would like to be able to monitor all the HTTP requests being made by a web page in an automated testing scenario.

I know how to drive browsers with Selenium.

Is there some kind of proxy that can be interacted with programatically. What would help is something that can be flagged to start recording all the HTTP requests then flagged to stop.

I believe FireFox has some proxy settings that can be driven from Selenium but Chrome is the highest priority browser for testing.

I have heard of BetaMax but think this is more about simulating and replaying REST calls rather than monitoring traffic programatically.

Comment: I am looking at WireShark but it seems a bit low level for what I am trying to do. I am not trying to debug entire networking protocols just monitor HTTP traffic.

Comment: Check [BrowserMobProxy](https://bmp.lightbody.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Hoverfly](https://docs.hoverfly.io/en/latest/index.html) and it has a mode where it [acts as a proxy](https://docs.hoverfly.io/en/latest/pages/keyconcepts/proxyserver.html). I haven't used it, but I believe you can replay whatever is recorded by the proxy when the requests are re-sent.  And yes [there is an API](https://docs.hoverfly.io/en/latest/pages/reference/api/api.html).